# Uso irónico de "lo tienes/llevas claro"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, expresiones, significado, dle

Hoy me ha dado por buscar en el diccionario las expresiones *tenerlo* o *llevarlo claro*, expresadas con intención irónica, y me he encontrado con que ninguna de las dos viene en el diccionario.

He comprobado que el DLE introduce voces o expresiones irónicas en el diccionario cuando su significado pretendido difiere considerablemente del literal. Ejemplo:

> **[angelito](https://dle.rae.es/?id=2dWApsH)**
>
> 4. m. irón. coloq. Persona de dudosas intenciones o de malas cualidades morales.

Según *Enclave RAE* hay 162 entradas en el diccionario registradas como "de intención irónica". Pensaba que *llevarlo/tenerlo claro* sería una de ellas. Su uso tiene ya varias décadas, como muestran los siguientes ejemplos:

> *—Es ése de negro, pero no entiendo, si no le conoces..., ¿por qué le miras tanto?
>
>   —Porque me gusta.
>
>   —¿Que te gusta? —soltó una carcajada—. Pues lo llevas claro, tía, es gay ¿sabes?, de toda la vida, ese rubito de ahí es su tronco.*
>
> Almudena Grandes, "Las edades de Lulú", 1989 (España).

Y la otra variante:

> *—¡Vaya tiritera que me ha dado! —exclamó. Luego miró fijamente a Maica y sonrió—. Las llevas calentitas, ¿eh?
>
>   —¿El qué?
>
>   —La papelina de caballo.
>
>   —Tú misma. Como no te lo hagas muy bien, lo tienes claro.*
>
> José Luis Tomás García, "La otra orilla de la droga", 1984 (España).

En ambos casos veo que la expresión *llevarlo/tenerlo claro* equivale a *[estar/ir apañado](https://dle.rae.es/?id=34NXdXt)*, que precisamente sí que está registrada como de uso irónico, para indicar "que alguien está equivocado con respecto a algo que cree o espera y va a encontrarse en una situación incómoda o difícil". Aquí en Andalucía usaríamos *[vas aviao](https://dle.rae.es/?id=4ZB97MJ)*. :-)

Sin embargo, el DLE solo registra la expresión en su uso literal:

> [**tener** algo **claro, ra**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=9PhBhLd#6kUzSE3)
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Estar seguro de ello, no tener dudas.

Preguntas que me surgen:

- ¿Está extendido el uso de estas expresiones irónicas? Solo veo casos en España y a partir de la década de 1980. ¿Se usan en Hispanoamérica?
- Veo que se usa también en femenino: "La llevamos clara". ¿Se usa tal vez más de esta forma?
- ¿Desde cuándo se usa? ¿Hay registros anteriores a la década de 1980?
- ¿Qué criterio sigue la RAE para introducir expresiones de intención irónica en el diccionario? ¿Podríamos recomendar en este caso la inclusión de ambas expresiones en el DLE?
- ¿Se podrían entender estas citadas expresiones en contextos irónicos incluso con el significado literal que propone la RAE para *tenerlo claro*? Si no, ¿veis bien la expresión sinónima que propongo o creéis que se puede dar otro significado?

Comment: @walen es una de las cosas que pregunto, si en realidad estoy malinterpretando el sentido de la expresión o no. :-) En todo caso, "llevarlo claro" no se recoge en el DLE de ninguna de las maneras, ni siquiera tiene sentido literal, y por lo que he visto se usa más que "tenerlo claro".

Comment: Al menos yo jamás había escuchado el término "llevarlo claro".

Comment: Puedo reportar que en Argentina se usa "tenerla/tenerlo  clara/claro" En ambos usos, literal o irónico, por supuesto, pero nunca "llevarlo"

Answer (score 1):

Trataré de responder la mayoría de tus preguntas.

En cuanto a si se usa en Hispanoamérica, sí. Se usan. Pero hay que darle énfasis de ironía para que no lo entienda la otra persona de forma literal. Por ejemplo, yo diciéndole a mi hija "Ya veo que sí ***te ha quedado claro*** cómo era tu tarea, lo has hecho todo al revés".

En cuanto a la expresión como tal que analizamos ahora, usamos más **tenerlo claro** / **haber quedado claro** / **estar claro**. No he escuchado el uso femenino, porque normalmente nos referimos a algo.

En cuanto a la fecha exacta de desde cuando se usa, no lo sé. Pero yo nací en 1981 y mis padres ya me enseñaban a hablar con expresiones de ese tipo, o sea que data de mucho antes de eso.

Finalmente, respecto a tus últimas 2 preguntas, desconozco también la forma en que la RAE pudiera incluir ese tipo de cambio de significado dentro de sus definiciones, derivado de que se trata de una expresión cuyo significado irónico depende totalmente del contexto, la entonación y de las frases adicionales que le pudieran seguir para darle dicho sentido. Tendría que incluir demasiados casos particulares en la mayoría de sus definiciones aclarando que en tono irónico podría significar lo contrario, cosa que más bien parece de la forma de hablar o de usar el lenguaje de las personas, no del significado real de las cosas. Quizá si alguna en particular es **muy recurrente**, se pueda optar por incluirla, a manera de brevario cultural, pero hacerlo para todas las definiciones existentes que pudieran ser susceptibles de adquirir un significado contrario con el uso de la ironía... sería totalmente fuera de contexto.

Espero haber sido claro.